# Jquery: slide down menu on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

I want to create an order form.
I have the following:

[image: Closed Form]

[image: Opened Form]

How can I animate it to slide down and up?
I know the function .slideDown() / .slideUp() or .slideToggle.
But I want to animate the button too. So, it's getting difficult for me.

Second question: Can I realize that without images?

Comment: _Can I realize that without images?_ .... sure you can make use of `html5` with `css3`.

Comment: Can I realize that without images? Yes. Can I realize that without jQuery? Yes. Can I realize that without JavaScript? Yes. You can use **[CSS transitions](https://www.google.nl/search?q=css+transitions)**

Comment: Thanks for the answers. How can I create the button? With canvas? What happens with older browsers, like IE 9?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/canvas IE9 supports canvas elements.

Comment: @dschazam But it don't supports CSS transitions. (http://caniuse.com/css-transitions)

Comment: You need to build something called 'fallback solution'. You can use http://modernizr.com/ to test if the browser supports, for example css-transitions.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery animate for margin-top. It looks better then animating height:

```
 $("#handler").click(function(){    

$('#opener, #closer').toggle();

var container = $( "#container" ),
    mt = container.css('margin-top').split('px')[0],
    op = (mt<0)?'+=169px':'-=169px';

 container.animate({
        'margin-top': op
    }, 500); 
});
```

Here is an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/290/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `postion: absolute` to button.

Check if this helps you.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wakgp

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to shape the handle instead of images and gradients for the background, but this should serve as a starting point for you.

```
$("#handler").click(function(){    

$('#opener, #closer').toggle();

var container = $( "#container" ),
    mt = container.css('margin-top').split('px')[0],
    op = (mt<0)?'+=169px':'-=169px';

 container.animate({
        'margin-top': op
    }, 500);
```

});

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/290/)